# Tornar a paginação do antd dinamica

Tags: react

Bom, dia. Estou trabalhando com paginação usando o componente do Antd Table, essa tabela faz a exibição de dados, eu estou tentando fazer com que quando o usuario clicar em um determinado numero, o front fará a requisição ao back para que seja exibido os dados.

Eu preciso alterar o State do componente da tabela na paginação para quando o usuario clicar em um numero da pagina, ele muda ela dinamicamente e faça a requisição ao back.

Codigo da minha tabela:

```
<AntdTable
    dataSource={data}
    columns={columns}
    className={css.table}
    locale={{
      emptyText: <Empty image={image} description={description} />,
    }}
    rowKey={rowKey}
    pagination={{ current: 1, total: 50 }}
  />
```

Quem puder me ajudar ficarei muito grato !

Comment: Giovanni, como que você faz a primeira requisição ao backend? Pergunto porque está setado na propriedade **pagination** current: 1 e total: 50. Esses valores poderiam estar um alguma outra variável possivelmente no state da aplicação.

Comment: entao, para testes eu coloquei como current:1 e total:50, mas a quantidade de paginas vao ser gerados dinamicamente quando forem carregados os dados vindo da API, eu apenas queria saber qual logica usar para mudar o state do componente do Antd para que quando o usuario clique em um numero, ele faça uma requisiçaõ ao back